# Upload image flutter web with dio formdata

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, form-data, dio

I am trying using file_picker and dio packages to upload files as form data.

This is for flutter web and it seems  `MultipartFile.fromFile` is not accepted.

What I tried is the following:

```
if (result != null) {    
  for (var file in result.files) {
    final formData = FormData.fromMap({
      ...someOtherData,
      'file': File(file.name), // <------ I guess this is where the issue is, I also tried file instead of File(file.name)
    });
    
    dio.post(
      url,
      data: formData,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found it, leaving here for someone having the same problem

```
if (result != null) {    
  for (var file in result.files) {
    final formData = FormData.fromMap({
      ...someOtherData,
      'file': MultipartFile.fromBytes(file.bytes as List<int>)
    });
    
    dio.post(
      url,
      data: formData,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this error: Unsupported operation: _Namespace.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still wondering how to get it working on both mobile and web (This is using the image_picker's PickedFile as the image variable type) :

```
 FormData body;
 final bytes = await image.readAsBytes();
 final MultipartFile file = MultipartFile.fromBytes(bytes, filename: "picture");
 MapEntry<String, MultipartFile> imageEntry = MapEntry("image", file);
 body.files.add(imageEntry);
```

**
The catch is that the filename is required on web and is automatically assigned on mobile.**

Comment: I get this error: Unsupported operation: _Namespace.